# ReSharper remove unused directives In file adds summary and header to methods and parameters

Tags: c#, resharper

When I use "Remove Unused Directives in file" reSharper command on current .cs file, the reSharper is puts summary and header on the all methods and parameters and namespaces. How can I rid this ?

ReSharper version : 9.0 Update 1 , Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Are you sure you're not doing it via a "code cleanup" operation which is configured with that? If never seen the straight "Removed unused using directives" action do anything else.

Comment: I use it alot but haven't seen resharper to do that. maybe some settings have been changed, you may want to reset to defaults. Resharper | Manage options | reset all settings

Comment: Yes, Im sure. I'm not doing via "code cleanup". Simply and only "Remove Unused Directives".  Is there any configuration connection between "Remove Unused Directives" and "Code Cleanup" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem:

StyleCop Extension doing this. 4.7 Beta version. When I uninstall the extension everthing is okay.

Answer (score 0):

With the new ReSharper (and StyleCop) using the "Remove unused directives in file" triggers a silent code cleanup. That's why it triggers the insertion of headers and the like. You can change what a silent code cleanup should do in the ReSharper code cleanup section. Although with the current StyleCop beta, it may still trigger it.